# Is there a penalty for deleting one's own upvoted comment?

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

Sometimes I delete my old comments to questions and answers if I don't think they are very useful any more. I did that today for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25647882/3681880). Maybe I shouldn't have, though. The comment had been upvoted once. Is there a penalty for deleting upvoted comments? Is there a way to undelete comments?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a penalty?

That depends on what you consider a penalty.  The thread may be lessened by the absence of your unique wisdom.  You may be denying yourself the accolades afforded one so astute and well-spoken.

However if you mean karma, badges, or any of the other gameified counters on SE...  Since you didn't get any for posting the comment, you don't lose any for deleting it.  The "unupvote" you see was attached to your answer, not your comment.

Comment: But I did loose 10 rep points (see screenshot images).

Comment: Unless someone unupvoted my answer at almost exactly the same time I deleted my comment. But that seems really unlikely.

Comment: Actually, that seems very likely.  You don't get karma up or down for comments.  Period.

Comment: @Suragch - It's like having votes on your post the second it goes up: weird but commonplace.

Comment: OK. I thought it might have been a bug, too. I was going to delete another upvoted comment to test it out, but I couldn't find any that I wanted to delete. I'll just take it as strange coincidence.